# call multiple functions in single onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to trigger two functions in a single onclick. I'm having a component to generate a "Star Rating" and "Comment Section", where the user can able to type comment and submit. At the time of submit, I want to call star rating and comment section. My problem is in the "Comment Section" I'm using onChange and then I'm converting it to onclick. But while submitting It's throwing an error like "BtnSubmit" is not a function. Could anyone guide me to achieve the output? Thanks in advance. Below is my code.

```
function StarRaating(props) {
  const { BtnSubmit } = props;
  let Comment = "";

  function handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
  const Star = ({ selected = false, onClick = (f) => f }) => (
    <div className={selected ? "star selected" : "star"} onClick={onClick} />
  );

  const [starsSelected, selectStar] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="star-rating">
        {[...Array(5)].map((n, i) => (
          <Star
            key={i}
            selected={i < starsSelected}
            onClick={() => selectStar(i + 1)}
          />
        ))}
        <p>{starsSelected}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="">
        <textarea
          name="comment"
          className=""
          placeholder="Add a new comment"
          onChange={handleChange}
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button
          className="Submit"
          onClick={(e) => {
            BtnSubmit(Comment);
            StarRaating();
          }}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default StarRaating;
```

Comment: Have you tried to console.log(BtnSubmit) yet?

Comment: Yes, it's coming as undefined.

Comment: So, you have to fix that first, There must be something wrong while you are passing props to `StarRaating`

Comment: What is `BtnSubmit` ? Is it a function passed through props? if so it should be `props.BtnSubmit()`

Comment: @sanketnaik He did it right, using destructuring right at the beginning of the function `StarRaating`